# Appending to a Pandas dataframe and specifying the row index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a little confused about the workings of the Pandas dataframe.

I have a pd.dataframe that looks like this:

```
        index        | val1 | val2
-----------------------------------
20-11-2017 22:33:20  | 0.33 | 05.43
23-11-2017 23:34:14  | 4.23 | 09.43
```

I'd like to append a row to it, and be able to specify the index, which in my case is a date and time.

I have tried the following methods:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['val1', 'val2'])
dataframe.loc[someDate] = [someVal, someVal]
```

This seems to overwrite if the index already exists, but I want to be able to have duplicate indices.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['val1', 'val2'])
record = pd.Series(
            index=[someDate],
            data=[someVal, someVal]
        )
dataframe.append(record)
```

This causes the application to hang without returning an exception or error.

Am I missing something? Is this the correct way of doing the thing I want to achieve?

Comment: use `pd.concat`

Comment: like @WoodyPride, said - concat may be better. However, I did a small test and `append` did work. What are you putting in as `someDate` and `someVal`?

Comment: The somDate thing is a python Date and the someVal’s are floats. I forgot to mention that is doesn’t fail directly, but after processing a few thousand records. I’ll give concat a try and let you guys know. Thanks!